# Dirac delta function definite integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\int_{-1}^{6}(1+e^{-5t})\delta(t-3)$dt

Would like suggestions on how to approach this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation).

Comment: Use the sifting property of the Dirac delta and note that $3\in (-1,6)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is the problem? The bounds of integration? Rewrite 
$$\int_{-1}^{6} f(t) \delta(t-3)dt =\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{[-1,6] }f(t) \delta(t-3)dt $$
This will, admittedly, not help as soon as the $\delta$ is concentrated on the boundary...

($\chi_I$ is the characteristic function of the set $I$, i.e. it is one on $I$ and $=0$ elsewhere).